# How do I save Dragonfly Images to a remote server using NGINX reverse proxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger, dragonfly-gem

PROBLEM:

Images are not getting read/write to my DB server file structure for Dragonfly. I am able to interact with my database through active record for all of my Ruby models. All my static assets are working. User generated images should be saved as www.test.example.com/media/AgGdsgDGsdgsDGSGdsgsdg...
on my remote server. However they are getting saved on whatever app server they get uploaded from.

BACKGROUND:

Ruby/Rails, Nginx, Passenger. We are moving from a single server solution to a 3 server solution. I have 2 app servers that sit behind a DB server. I am using Dragonfly Gem for user generated images and other content. On our current, single server setup, everything just points to localhost and works great.

10.102.66.4 is my lan IP for the DB server.

APP SERVERS NGINX.CONF:

```
user  pete;
...
http {
  passenger_pre_start http://example.com;
  passenger_pre_start http://example.com:3000;
  ...
  proxy_cache_path /home/pete/example/shared/tmp/dragonfly levels=2:2
  keys_zone=dragonfly:100m inactive=30d max_size=1g;
  ...
  server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite     ^   https://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl default deferred;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server.key;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    root /home/pete/example/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;

    location /media {
      proxy_pass http://10.102.66.4:443;
      proxy_cache dragonfly;
      proxy_cache_valid      200  30d;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

DB SERVER NGINX.CONF:

```
user pete;
...
http {
  sendfile on;
  ...
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  ...
  large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server.key;

    location / {
      try_files $uri @app;
    }

    location @app {
      proxy_set_header host $Host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      root /home/pete/example/shared/;
    }
  }
}
```

DRAGONFLY.RB:

```
 require 'dragonfly'
 app = Dragonfly[:images]
 app.configure_with(:imagemagick)
 app.configure_with(:rails)

 if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) 
   app.define_macro(ActiveRecord::Base, :image_accessor) 
   app.define_macro(ActiveRecord::Base, :file_accessor) 
 end
```

WHAT IVE TRIED:

'chown -R pete:pete /home/pete/example/current/public' and the permissions look correct.

Restarted server/nginx/ruby/etc...

Add 'large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;' to nginx.conf

ERRORS/LOGS:

CHROME CONSOLE:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

NGINX ERROR.LOG (Yes.. I know it says 'warn')

```
 2015/06/25 11:49:11 [warn] 25591#0: *345 a client request body is buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/body/0000000002, client: 173.204.167.103, server: example.com, request: "POST /offices/1-big-o/users/1-peterb HTTP/1.1", host: "test.example.com", referrer: "https://test.example.com/offices/1-big-o/users/1-peterb/edit"
```

NGINX ACCESS.LOG:

```
 [25/Jun/2015:11:49:14 -0700] "GET /media/W1siZiIsIjIwMTUvMDYvMjUvMTFfNDlfMTFfNDcxXzhfYml0X21scF9vY19fX2xvY2tlX3R1bWJsZXJfYnlfbmlnaHRzaGFkZTQyNF9kNXppdmpmLmpwZyJdXQ HTTP/1.0" 400 681 "https://test.example.com/offices/1-big-o/users/1-peterb/edit" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.125 Safari/537.36
```

curl -k https://10.102.66.4:443

```
 <html>
 <head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
 <hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
 </body>
 </html>
```

UPDATE 1:

It seems that INSTEAD of saving my files on the DB server, it is saving them locally to my app server. The file structure is correct... Just wrong server.

Comment: What is proxy_pass set as?

Comment: the remote servers lan ip

Answer (score 0):

Since dragonfly runs on the app servers it saves them there. If you want them to be accessible by the reverse proxy you could setup nfs or some other file sharing system. Then the files could be save locally but accessed by the proxy server.

Comment: There is no way to have nginx forward the upstream to my remote server?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. I thought you indicated that you were expecting the files to be on the db server; so I thought you wanted to serve them directly from the db server.

Comment: Sorry. Yes this is all user generated content that I want to serve/store. All my other assets are precompiled off server and uploaded to each app server